# Syntax problem with `LocatorPane`

Tags: function-construction, syntax

I am trying to create an image function:

```
image = Rasterize[ImageResize[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Mandrill"}], 300], ImageResolution -> 72];

Manipulate[LocatorPane[Dynamic[{p1, p2}], 
Grid[{{
 ap[{pix[image, p1], pix[image, p2]}], 
 image
}}]], 
{{p1, {1, 1}}, Locator, Appearance -> Style[Graphics[{White, Disk[{1, 1}, 1.2], 
     RGBColor[PixelValue[image, p1]], Disk[{1, 1}, 1]}, ImageSize -> 20]]}, 
{{p2, {1, 1}}, Locator, Appearance -> Style[Graphics[{White, Disk[{1, 1}, 1.2], 
     RGBColor[PixelValue[image, p2]], Disk[{1, 1}, 1]}, ImageSize -> 20]]}]
```

[image]

but when I try to add a colour wheel:

```
Manipulate[LocatorPane[Dynamic[{p1, p2}], 
Grid[{{
 ap[{pix[image, p1], pix[image, p2]}], 
 (*colour wheel added here*)
 cw[{pix[image, p1], pix[image, p2]}], 
 image
}}]], 
{{p1, {1, 1}}, Locator, Appearance -> Style[Graphics[{White, Disk[{1, 1}, 1.2], 
     RGBColor[PixelValue[image, p1]], Disk[{1, 1}, 1]}, ImageSize -> 20]]}, 
{{p2, {1, 1}}, Locator, Appearance -> Style[Graphics[{White, Disk[{1, 1}, 1.2], 
     RGBColor[PixelValue[image, p2]], Disk[{1, 1}, 1]}, ImageSize -> 20]]}]
```

[image]

The locators jump to the coordinates in the colour wheel rather than the image. Where am I going wrong with my syntax?

I am using the above with with these functions:

```
pix[image_, px_] := (Evaluate[InputForm[ColorConvert[PixelValue[image, px], "HSB"]]][[1,#1]] & ) /@ 
Range[3]; 
cw[list_] := Graphics[{Apply[Polygon[{{0, 0}, First[#1], First[#2]}, 
    VertexColors -> Hue /@ {{0, 0, 1}, Last[#1], Last[#2]}] & , 
  Partition[(Append[#1, First[#1]] & )[Table[{r*{Cos[phi], Sin[phi]}, phi/(2*Pi)}, 
      {phi, 0, 2*Pi, 0.1}, {r, 0, 1, 0.1}][[All,-1,{1, 2}]]], 2, 1], {1}], 
 EdgeForm[Directive[White]], 
 ((Thread[{Hue[#1, #2, #3], Disk[#2*{Cos[360*#1*Degree], Sin[360*#1*Degree]}, 0.1]}] & ) @@ 
    #1 & ) /@ list}]; 
ap[list_] := (ArrayPlot[Partition[Apply[Hue[#1, #2, #3] & , #1, {1}], UpTo[3]], ImageSize -> 200] & )[
list];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `LocatorPane` seems to get confused about what part of the 2nd argument is supposed to be the domain of the locators. It's better to disentangle this a bit:

```
DynamicModule[{p1 = {1, 1}, p2 = {1, 1}},
 Grid[{{
    Dynamic[ap[{pix[image, p1], pix[image, p2]}]],(*colour wheel added here*)           
    Dynamic[cw[{pix[image, p1], pix[image, p2]}]],
    LocatorPane[Dynamic[{p1, p2}],
     image,
     Appearance -> {Dynamic @ Style[Graphics[{White, Disk[{1, 1}, 1.2], 
           RGBColor[PixelValue[image, p1]], Disk[{1, 1}, 1]}, 
          ImageSize -> 20]],
       Dynamic @ Style[Graphics[{White, Disk[{1, 1}, 1.2], 
           RGBColor[PixelValue[image, p2]], Disk[{1, 1}, 1]}, 
          ImageSize -> 20]]
       }
     ]
    }}
  ]
 ]
```

Comment: perfect! thank you!