# Building dynamic functions

Tags: function-construction, dynamic

When I'm trying to build `Dynamic` functions (as in [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/241877/syntax-problem-with-locatorpane)), I often end up with long repeated lists of dynamic variables, like this:

```
Grid[{{
LocatorPane[
Dynamic[{p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8, p9, p10, p11, p12}], 
image, Appearance -> {Dynamic@
   Style[Graphics[{White, Disk[{1, 1}, 1.2], 
      RGBColor[PixelValue[image, p1]], Disk[{1, 1}, 1]}, 
     ImageSize -> 20]], 
  Dynamic@Style[
    Graphics[{White, Disk[{1, 1}, 1.2], 
      RGBColor[PixelValue[image, p2]], Disk[{1, 1}, 1]}, 
     ImageSize -> 20]],
  Dynamic@
   Style[Graphics[{White, Disk[{1, 1}, 1.2], 
      RGBColor[PixelValue[image, p3]], Disk[{1, 1}, 1]}, 
     ImageSize -> 20]],
  Dynamic@
   Style[Graphics[{White, Disk[{1, 1}, 1.2], 
      RGBColor[PixelValue[image, p4]], Disk[{1, 1}, 1]}, 
     ImageSize -> 20]], (*...*)
```

..etc. Is there an elegant workaround for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SeedRandom[1];
pts = RandomSample[Tuples@Range[ImageDimensions@image], 9];

DynamicModule[{plist = pts}, 
 LocatorPane[Dynamic[plist], image, 
  Appearance -> Table[With[{i = i}, 
     Graphics[{White, Disk[{1, 1}, 1.2], 
       Dynamic @ RGBColor[PixelValue[image, plist[[i]]]], 
       Disk[{1, 1}, 1]}, ImageSize -> 20]], {i, Length@pts}]]]
```

[image]

```
DynamicModule[{plist = pts}, 
 Grid[{{Dynamic[ap[pix[image, #] & /@ plist]], 
    Dynamic[cw[pix[image, #] & /@ plist]], 
    LocatorPane[Dynamic[plist], image, 
     Appearance -> Table[With[{i = i}, 
        Graphics[{White, Disk[{1, 1}, 1.2], 
          Dynamic @ RGBColor[PixelValue[image, plist[[i]]]], 
          Disk[{1, 1}, 1]}, ImageSize -> 20]], {i, Length @ pts}]]}}]]
```

[image]

Comment: amazing, thank you. Will help enormously with future function construction

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is. Controls can often be linked to parts of variables. Taking your previous example:

```
DynamicModule[{point = {{1, 1}, {100, 100}}}, 
 Grid[{{Dynamic[
     ap[{pix[image, point[[1]]], 
       pix[image, point[[2]]]}]],(*colour wheel added here*)
    Dynamic[cw[{pix[image, point[[1]]], pix[image, point[[2]]]}]], 
    LocatorPane[Dynamic[point], image, 
     Appearance -> {Dynamic @ Style[Graphics[{White, Disk[{1, 1}, 1.2], 
           RGBColor[PixelValue[image, point[[1]]]], Disk[{1, 1}, 1]}, 
          ImageSize -> 20]], 
       Dynamic@Style[ Graphics[{White, Disk[{1, 1}, 1.2], 
           RGBColor[PixelValue[image, point[[2]]]], Disk[{1, 1}, 1]}, 
          ImageSize -> 20]]}]}}]]
```

You can also use associations to make it a bit easier to read:

```
DynamicModule[{point = <|"p1" -> {1, 1}, "p2" -> {100, 100}|>}, 
 Grid[{{Dynamic[
     ap[{pix[image, point["p1"]], 
       pix[image, point["p2"]]}]],(*colour wheel added here*)
    Dynamic[cw[{pix[image, point["p1"]], pix[image, point["p2"]]}]], 
    LocatorPane[Dynamic[{point["p1"], point["p2"]}], image, 
     Appearance -> {Dynamic @ Style[Graphics[{White, Disk[{1, 1}, 1.2], 
           RGBColor[PixelValue[image, point["p1"]]], Disk[{1, 1}, 1]},
           ImageSize -> 20]], 
       Dynamic@Style[Graphics[{White, Disk[{1, 1}, 1.2], 
           RGBColor[PixelValue[image, point["p2"]]], Disk[{1, 1}, 1]},
           ImageSize -> 20]]}]}}]]
```

Note, however, that you can't do something like `TrackedSymbols :> {point[[1]]}`. So if you have many interactive elements, it can be tricky to tell Mathematica to selectively update only parts of the interface: when `point` changes, everything will have to be updated, even if you know in advance that certain elements don't need it.

Comment: thanks for your answer, was looking for something more along lines of long list building as in kglr 's answer though